# saving users in custom table in openfire xmpp

Tags: mysql, xmpp, openfire

I have installed openfire on windows machine and pointing to our mysql database.I have created test users in openfire and testing with xmpp client on my machine . Everything is working fine.
I have opened our mysql database and seen so many tables are created from openfire where tablename starts with **of** like for example **ofuser** which stores user registration information.
Now instead of storing user registration information in **ofuser** ,I want to store user registration information in my custom table like for example **chat_registrations**.
Is it possible in openfire, if so how to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with Openfire custom DB integration. Documentation to that: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html

Comment: Why down vote? Please let me know if there is anything wrong with the question so that I will rectify myself

Comment: I don't down voted you

Comment: @Roman S, Thanks for the link. I didnt mean u down voted.

Comment: hey i am facing similar issue.. can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but for this you have to modify [openfire](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire) from source and build the system for yourself. To do this fork openfire from github, clone your repository in pc, open source code with you favourite IDE, then modify  openfire's sql queries related to ofUser table. You will get them in src/database/openfire*.sql . Build the modified system and install it to server.